# How to style Semantic UI disabled button

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

There seems to be an automatic greying of the original button color when applying "disabled" to `<Button>`. I want to change the color completely.

Current button:

```
<Button disabled>{example}</Button>
```

Current styling that is not overwriting the greying:

```
.labels .button{
  background-color: #6363FA;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #F2F1F7;
}
```

Hoping to be able to apply a new background-color for disabled somewhere

Answer (score 0):

#### From my experience, here's one good way you can restyle a Button like that

*(Follow the guide here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming/#theming-with-create-react-app first if you haven't setup theming!!)*

Go and edit `some-location/semantic-ui/site/elements/button.overrides`, add a class like `.ui.huge.disabled.button` for a `<Button />` with properties `size='huge' disabled`

[sample button disabled css class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNBKm.png)
Which will result in something like this:
[button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T967G.png)
By the way, I found that class name above by inspecting it in the browser:
[css class in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TItTe.png)

I hope this is clear! If you have any questions, let me know :)

PS: Sorry didn't have enough rep to embed images...

EDIT: Forgot to mention, in the CSS example above, `@gold` and `@black` are custom colors I added into `semantic-ui/site/globals/site.variables`

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler way. I'm using Semantic UI React - not sure if that matters.

I have a css class for the button:

```
.main-app .landing-page .quick-search {
  background-color: #41B3A3;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

and I add one like this and it works to respond to the `disabled` property

```
.main-app .landing-page .quick-search:disabled {
  background-color: #f5f7f6;
  color: rgba(56, 143, 89, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: So I've looked a bit more into this, and `:disabled` is a pseudo-class that responds to the elements state, and isn't directly picking up on the property `disabled` property passed to the element in jsx like I'd first assumed. Here's some info: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#UIstates